# Tkinter button press for loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to interactively create a polygon using mouse clicks for a series of figures and store the coordinates.  As of right now, I am only able to do this for one figure because the loop continues and does not wait for the click event to finish.  What am I doing wrong?  Should all of my data processing prior to plotting be done inside of my onclick function?  Here is a snippet of my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onclick(event):
    global ix, iy
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

    global coords
    coords.append((ix, iy))

    if len(coords) == 8: # allow for 8 clicks
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        plt.close()

for j in np.arange(len(folders)):
    # loop through folders
    for i in np.arange(len(files)):
        # loop through files in folders

        # do data processing

        coords = []

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
        cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

**UPDATE**: I've added a simple example to illustrate what I am trying to do.  The code does run but it does not do what I want it to do.  I would like to plot a Basemap, plot a point on the map 4 different times, and for each instance get the mouse coordinates for 8 clicks.  As of right now, it really does not do what I want at all.  I don't typically use functions and am new to Tkinter, so any help is appreciated.

```
from pylab import *
close("all")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

def onclick(event):
    global coords
    global ix, iy
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata

    global coords
    coords.append((ix, iy))
    print 'x = %d, y = %d'%(ix, iy)

    plotloop()

    if len(coords) == 8:
        plt.close()
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)

def plotloop():
    plotlat = [35.,36.,37.,38.]
    plotlon = [-125.,-125.,-125.,-125.]
    x, y = bm(plotlon, plotlat)

    global i
    for i in np.arange(0,5):
        if i == 4:
            plt.close()
            fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        else:
            bm.plot(x[i],y[i],color='r')
            plt.show()

ll_lat_nam = 30.
ll_lon_nam = -130.
ur_lat_nam = 45.
ur_lon_nam = -115.
lon_0_nam = (ll_lon_nam + ur_lon_nam)/2.

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
bm = Basemap(projection='lcc',resolution='i',llcrnrlon=ll_lon_nam,llcrnrlat=ll_lat_nam,urcrnrlon=ur_lon_nam,urcrnrlat=ur_lat_nam,lon_0=-95.,lat_0=25.)

bm.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.25)
bm.drawstates(linewidth=1.25)
bm.drawcountries(linewidth=1.25)
bm.drawparallels(np.arange(20.,60.,5.),labels=[True,False,False,False],zorder=5,fontsize=12,linewidth=1.0)
bm.drawmeridians(np.arange(-140.,-100.,5.),labels=[False,False,False,True],zorder=5,fontsize=12,linewidth=1.0)

coords = []
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

Comment: Is your `for j in np.arange()` loop meant to be inside your `oneclick()` function?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I added the loops inside of the function, but I am still having issues.  I have posted an update.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW `folders` and `files` refers to nothing in your code.

Comment: I was not telling you to move the `for j in np.arange()` I was just asking if it was meant to be because some times there are indention mistakes when posting code. I think you may wish to have the `for` loop in its own function and to call that function each time you need to. I cannot test you code fully because some of your code just doesn't work. Example. What is `folders` and `files` there is no reference to a variable of any kind with those names in your code.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Apologies -- I reposted and included a snippet of code that works.  Thanks for your help.